# Finding the right attributes for maximizing another attribute

Tags: optimization, statistics, artificial-intelligence, data-analysis

I have a model with several attributes/properties that are fixed (approximately 15 independent attributes).

The same model has another attribute which is the most interesting to me. I want to maximize a certain value of that attribute.

I would like to find what fixed attribute values influence the most the interesting attribute based on my data. I think this is a stats problem but I'm not sure.

A real life example would be a database of mortgages with all the following fixed attributes : bank branch, postal code, employment, salary, credit score, relationship status, number of children, etc. Then I have one attribute that is whether the mortgage has defaulted.

I would like to find what are the fixed attributes that have the biggest impact on reducing the defaults on these mortgages. The answer to that question would be more than one set of "optimal" attributes. It could be a coefficient for each attribute or combination of attributes that correlates to a low default rate.

Basically, I don't event know how to ask my question, I just have an idea of what I am looking for and the best way to do it (sorry)!

Comment: How did you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an ML approach with a regression model based on Gradient descent, decision trees, SVM, or ensembles, etc. You question is very unspecific.